# Allocate memory in a function, then use it outside

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I want to allocate memory inside a function with `malloc` and then return the buffer. Then I want to be able to `strcpy` a string into that buffer from outside of the function.

**Here is my current code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char allocate_mem(void) {
    char *buff = malloc(124); // no cast is required; its C

    return buff // return *buff ?
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buff = allocate_mem();
    strcpy(buff, "Hello World");
    free(buff);
    return 0;
}
// gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0
```

Comment: wrong prototype use `char *allocate_mem(void)`

Comment: And `char * buff = allocate_mem();`

Comment: you should do some testing to learn how these things work. malloc allocates buffer on the heap, not the stack, so you can use it outside of the function where it's called. local variables in a function are allocated on the stack and disappear when the function exits.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre @ # gspr. Great, can you explain why this happend?

Comment: `char *` is also a type. If you want to return a pointer, you have to use a pointer type to return & hold the data

Comment: @johnelemans I try to learn as much as possible about memory and especially about pointers. I came from Python, a completely different world

Comment: you can also use `strdup` if you want to allocate+copy a string

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks. By the way, what's the problem with the question? I do not see a problem with the wording. I would love to know why I got a downvote

Comment: ArlichBachman.  Save time.  Enable more warnings on your compiler to rapidly get feedback that something is amiss.  Much faster than SO.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I got a lot of warnings and issues, but my compiler's issues are not very understandable. I can guess that this is the correct type of questions.

Comment: ArlichBachman, to improve posts, do not omit useful compiler warnings from the post.  They may be not very understandable for you, but easily searchable and useful to others.

Comment: @ArlichBachman problem is that C is well established here and those kind of questions show a very low skill in C. You can't learn C by just asking questions on SO. See how answers fare too: no votes ATM

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre For a person who started studying C two days ago, I think I'm progressing pretty well. We were all like that, you too. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not saying you're not progressing or such, but after 2 days, you need some more reading documentation & tutorials & examples. If you ask a question here in C (or C++, or python or any well established language) it has to be a _very good_ question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I understand, I promise to improve my questions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `buff` within the function has the type `char *`. So if you want to return the pointer then the function has to have the return type `char *`.

```
char * allocate_mem(void) {
    char *buff = malloc(124); // no cast is required; its C

    return buff // return *buff ?
}
```

And in main you have to write

```
char *buff = allocate_mem();
```

Pay attention to that it is not a good idea to use the magic number `124` in the function.

A more meaningful function could look the following way

```
char * allocate_mem( const char *s ) {
    char *buff = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 ); // no cast is required; its C
    
    if ( buff ) strcpy( buff, s );

    return buff // return *buff ?
}
```

And in main you could write

```
char *buff = allocate_mem( "Hello World" );
//...
free(buff);
```

Another approach is to use as a parameter an integer value that will specify the size of the allocated memory. For example

```
char * allocate_mem( size_t n ) {
    char *buff = malloc( n ); // no cast is required; its C

    return buff // return *buff ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `allocate_mem` creates `char *` but then it returns a `char`.

return  a `char*` and store it as a `char *buff` the rest of your code should work.